# How do I reference my javascript files with this folder structure?

Tags: html, spring

This is a very simple thing that I can't seem to get to work.  What is the correct way for referencing my resources folder in my script and link tags?  Is there a trick to this since my URLs are mapped to Spring resources?  Do I have to do anything special since my resources folder isn't in my WEB-INF folder?  Do I need to move it into the WEB-INF folder?  If I do move it there, how would it be referenced inside the WEB-INF folder.  I have tried everything I can think of, including....

With folder in current position -

```
/WebContent/resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
/resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
../../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
/../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
/../../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
```

With folder inside WEB-INF -

```
/resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
../../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
/../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
/../../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
```

Are any of these right?

I'm getting this in my console when I use 'resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js' -

```
May 23, 2011 11:30:19 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet     noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI 
[/ProjectName/resources/styles/global.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

home.jsp -

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
  title goes here
</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebContent/resources/scripts/global.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebContent/resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebContent/resources/styles/global.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
        function(){
        alert('hello');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ${message}
    <input id="inputField"></input>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/global.css" media="screen"
```

Comment: @miguel-rodrigues this path gives me the warning I have included in the question -

Comment: you are correct. How is your <servlet-mapping> on your web.xml?

Comment: Doest this help you? 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?87101-No-mapping-found-for-HTTP-request-with-URI

Comment: @miguel-rodrigues this is my <servlet-mapping> - 

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @miguel-rodrigues the link you provided is exactly the issue I'm having.  Thanks for your help.